# Read a file and affect the splitting result in an array with bash

Tags: arrays, bash

My code read a file by line and split each line by a comma ; or space and the results is affected to an array, but the proble is that i can't read the elmen of the array

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
name=$line
    echo "Name read from file - $name"
 arr=$(echo $name | tr ";" "\n")

echo ${arr[1]}

for x in $arr
do
    echo "> [$x]"
var1=$x
var2=$x
done

done < "$filename"
```

the problem is in the command:

```
echo ${arr[1]}
```

the file that i use contain line :

```
car; vehicle
computer;apple
```

Comment: I think your assumption that `arr=$(echo $name | tr ";" "\n")` is creating an array needs to be re-examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To loop through an array:

```
for x in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "> [$x]"
done
```

The `${arr[@]}` expansion will include the entire array, while `$arr` alone only includes the first array element.

However if you use `read -ra` with custom `IFS` then you can directly read each delimited line into an array:

```
while IFS=';' read -ra arr; do
   printf "[%s]\n" "${arr[@]}"
   echo '----------'
done < file
```

**Output:**

```
[car]
[vehicle]
----------
[computer]
[apple]
----------
```

Comment: i want to affect var1=${arr[1]}  and var2=${arr[2]}, but the problem is that when i did echo ${arr[1]} this give nothing, so i can't access to the array with the index number

Comment: What valued do you want in `var1` and `var2`?

Comment: in var1=${arr[1]} and var2=${arr[1]} but the problem echo ${arr[1]} return nothing, so in var1= car and var2=vehicle

Comment: [See it working here in this demo](http://ideone.com/FDFgUR) Whatever is not working please provide a demo like this and I will suggest you a fix.